# Behavior of Regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to javascript and have not much idea about regular expressions. Please help me in understanding the following code.

```
var r = new RegExp("^.*?https://www\\.facebook\\.com/servlet/SignOn.*$","i");
var content = "https://www.facebook.com/servlet/SignOn?msg=You+are+not+authorized+to+vie…r+level+of+authority.&cm_sp=TopNav-_-servlet-_-MMM&goto=MembersMainMenu%3F";
console.log(content.search(r));// It gives me 0
```

But when I change the regex to

```
var r = new RegExp("^.*?https://www\\.facebook\\.com/servlet/SignOn?msg=.*$","i");
console.log(content.search(r));// It gives me -1 , why??
```

Comment: There is a star after . in the regex

Answer (score 0):

`n?` means n is optional you need `n\?`